# How can I extract consecutive days from a series?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function to find the start and end index of consecutive days in an array.

Here is my example input:

```
var input =  [
    '2018-06-11',
    '2018-06-12',
    '2018-06-15',
    '2018-06-16',
    '2018-06-17',
    '2018-06-19'
];
```

I would expect my output to be:

```
var expectedOutput = [{
        start: '2018-06-11',
        end: '2018-06-12'
    },
    {
        start: '2018-06-15',
        end: '2018-06-17'
    },
    {
        start: '2018-06-19',
        end: '2018-06-19'
    }
];
```

So I want to have the start/end date for the consecutive days found.

Individual days should be on their own.

I've written an algorithm but it stopped on the first day.

```
function extractConsecutiveDays(input, index) {

    if (input == null || input.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    if(isConsecutiveDay(input[index], input[index + 1])) {
        return extractConsecutiveDays(input, index + 1);
    }

    var obj = {
        start: input[0],
        end: input[index]
    };

    input.splice(0, index);
    return obj;
}
```

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aubz88/tz24o0fk/

Comment: *"How can I use recursion to extract consecutive days from a series?"* While you probably *can* use recursion for this, it's not necessary and doesn't immediately seem very useful. Why are you looking at recursion?

Comment: Because I don't know how to solve this problem at all.

Comment: If you're open to a non-recursive solution, probably best to edit the question to just ask about finding the consecutive segments, and then mention that your attempt included recursion but you don't need recursion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I asked above why you wanted a recursive solution (the problem isn't really suited to it) and it [sounds like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208269/how-can-i-use-recursion-to-extract-consecutive-days-from-a-series/51208464#comment89397570_51208269) you're open to a non-recursive one. If so, see comments:

```
function findConsecutive(array) {
    var result = [];
    var current = null;
    // Loop through building up each result, starting a new entry each
    // time we find a non-consecutive day
    array.forEach(function(entry) {
        // If this is the first pass or this entry isn't consecutive with
        // the last, start a new entry
        if (!current || !areConsecutive(current.end, entry)) {
            result.push(current = {
              start: entry,
              end: entry
            });
        } else {
            // It's consecutive, just extend the last one
            current.end = entry;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var input =  [
    '2018-06-11',
    '2018-06-12',
    '2018-06-15',
    '2018-06-16',
    '2018-06-17',
    '2018-06-19'
];

// I *THINK* this `areConsecutive` implementation is reliable across DST
// boundaries (http://jsfiddle.net/em8xqtc2/3/), but be sure to test...
var ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 86400000;
function toDateUTC(str) {
  var parts = str.split("-");
  return Date.UTC(+parts[0], +parts[1] - 1, +parts[2]);
}
function areConsecutive(a, b) {
  return toDateUTC(b) - toDateUTC(a) == ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS;
}

function findConsecutive(array) {
    var result = [];
    var current = null;
    // Loop through building up each result, starting a new entry each
    // time we find a non-consecutive day
    array.forEach(function(entry) {
        // If this is the first pass or this entry isn't consecutive with
        // the last, start a new entry
        if (!current || !areConsecutive(current.end, entry)) {
            result.push(current = {
              start: entry,
              end: entry
            });
        } else {
            // It's consecutive, just extend the last one
            current.end = entry;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var expectedOutput = findConsecutive(input);
console.log(expectedOutput);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

I used just ES5-level features there, since you appeared to in your solution. Not much changes if you use ES2015+, though:

```js
const input =  [
    '2018-06-11',
    '2018-06-12',
    '2018-06-15',
    '2018-06-16',
    '2018-06-17',
    '2018-06-19'
];

// I *THINK* this `areConsecutive` implementation is reliable across DST
// boundaries (http://jsfiddle.net/em8xqtc2/3/), but be sure to test...
const ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 86400000;
function toDateUTC(str) {
  const [year, month, day] = str.split("-");
  return Date.UTC(+year, +month - 1, +day);
}
function areConsecutive(a, b) {
  return toDateUTC(b) - toDateUTC(a) == ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS;
}

function findConsecutive(array) {
    const result = [];
    let current = null;
    // Loop through building up each result, starting a new entry each
    // time we find a non-consecutive day
    for (const entry of array) {
        // If this is the first pass or this entry isn't consecutive with
        // the last, start a new entry
        if (!current || !areConsecutive(current.end, entry)) {
            result.push(current = {
              start: entry,
              end: entry
            });
        } else {
            // It's consecutive, just extend the last one
            current.end = entry;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const expectedOutput = findConsecutive(input);
console.log(expectedOutput);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: To find consecutive dates, you may convert both the strings to date objects and check the diff of their millis. If the diff is 86400000, then the dates are consecutive.

Comment: @31piy - Thanks. Does that work reliably across DST boundaries when the input is date-only?

Comment: Should work, I guess, because both the date objects will be in machine's TZ. Need to check though.

Comment: @31piy - I couldn't convince myself it did. :-) It *seems* to: http://jsfiddle.net/em8xqtc2/ There's a DST boundary in there, but I'm getting a whole number. If the DST boundary were a problem, I'd expect a fractional number.

Comment: @31piy - The date-only form should be parsed as UTC according to the spec, but sadly the spec has varied on this (ES2015, ES2016, and ES2017 all had changes in this regard). So I forced UTC and used the milliseconds comparison. That should be reliable across DST. Thanks!